# apache jmeter for setting up certificates for massl connection

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I wanted to setup jmeter to stress test my server (tomcat) serving APIs. As part of which my backend server is MASSL enabled and hence i need to configure the same in jmeter. I have .cert and .key files (with a pass phrase) which I configure in postman to trigger the API endpoints.

How to setup these certificate configurations in Jmeter?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert these certificates into something JMeter can understand (a .jks or .p12 [Java Keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore)), the conversion can be made using [OpenSSL](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html) tool or a GUI-based solution like [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

Once you have the Java Keystore with your certificate(s) you can "tell" JMeter to use this keystore for sending client-side certificates by following JMeter Properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your keystore password
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType= your keystore type (JKS or PKCS12)
```

the settings need to go into [*system.properties* file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2/bin/system.properties) or can be passed to JMeter via [-D command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your keystore password ....
```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates/)